# Why does Laravel 5 auto update my date field?

Tags: laravel, timestamp, laravel-5

I want to update a field (`status`) on the model. I would retrieve from DB and assign a new value to `status` column. But after the model saved, I saw another date field (`published_at`) also changed to same as `updated_at`.
The action run when user click on a link as [http://localhost/dashboard/gallery/publish/1](http://localhost:8097/dashboard/gallery/publish/1).

I don't know why the `published_at` updated auto and same as `updated_at`?

Here is **Controller code**:

```
<?php 
class GalleryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Approve to publish the gallery on the web.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getPublish($id)
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();       
        $gallery->status = Gallery::STT_PUBLISH;
        $gallery->save();
        return redirect( route('backend::gallery.edit',[$gallery->id]) )->with('status', 'Done');
    }
}
?>
```

and **Gallery Model**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Gallery extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;
  protected $table = 'gallery';
  protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'content', 'category_id', 'type'];
  protected $guarded = ['published_at','creator_id','thumbnail'];
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'published_at'];
}
?>
```

and **Migration func**:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('gallery', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();   
            $table->tinyInteger('type')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->default(0); 
            $table->string('thumbnail');   
            $table->string('title');   
            $table->text('content');
            $table->integer('status')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->timestamp('published_at');
            $table->integer('creator_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();            
            $table->index(['slug']);
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
        Schema::table('gallery', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category');
            $table->foreign('creator_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I see this config in Migration function makes problem, here:
`$table->timestamp('published_at');`

And this statement creates SQL like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `gallery` ( 
    ...
     `published_at` Timestamp NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ...
)
```

So, how to set up a timestamp field, which is not auto update on current time?

**UPDATE 2**

Done, I modify the migration, just use `dateTime` instead of `timestamp`.

Use it, `$table->dateTime('published_at');`, this statement will not auto update on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: try this,  remove 'published_at' from $dates

Comment: @SarangaR I tried it before but it's not done

Comment: @TimothyKruger I agree about timestamp problem but not updated_at or deleted_at. Please see my update at last of question. Thanks!

Comment: Add public $timestamps = false; to your Model just below protected $table = 'gallery', Just an assumption although this will probably cause the published_at and updated_at columns not to be set when saving records.

Comment: @TimothyKruger Thank you Tim, I still want to keep updated_at auto update. I found the resolution and updated my question.

Comment: @Davuz great I'm glad you managed to resolve the problem, and thanks for the update.

Comment: @Davuz it's been 6 hours since I started debugging this problem. I was going nuts

Comment: Please unaccept the currently accpeted solution, and accept the newly added correct solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46620583/1828637

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like what is happening is that MySQL (or whichever database you are using) is updating the date, not Laravel.

You need to change:

```
$table->timestamp('published_at');
```

to:

```
$table->dateTime('published_at');
```

Then do a `php artisan migrate:refresh` to rollback and recreate your tables.

Comment: This is awesome answer I spent 12 hours trying to figure out what is happening on my logic thank you so much buddy.

Answer (score 12):

This Post is old but for anyone who got this problem here is the simplest solution. In your migration the timestamp field just has to be nullable. Than there will no auto update trigger on this field.

```
$table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
```

No need for using `$table->dateTime()` instead of `$table->timestamp()`.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much for sharing this solution! This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: This solution did not fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem of Laravel, but a "feature" of MySQL.

According to the [reference manual MySQL 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

> TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns have no automatic properties unless
>   they are specified explicitly, with this exception: If the
>   explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable is disabled, the first
>   TIMESTAMP column has both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if neither is specified explicitly.

The official site removed reference manual for older version, but when I google for the problem, from the sources that also mention about the problem, it seems that the feature was there for older version of MySQL too.

Therefore, instead of changing `$table->timestamp('published_at');` to `$table->dateTime('published_at');`, you may also try to solve the problem by

1. giving a default value to the timestamp. e.g. `$table->timestamp('published_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));` or `$table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable()` (where the default value is null)
2. moving the line later then `$table->timestamps();` so that `pulibhsed_at` is not the firs timestamp. The default `created_at` and `updated_at` is nullable (i.e. having default value null) an will not trigger the "feature"

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change migration to

```
$table->dateTime('published_at');
```

Just make it

```
$table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
```

To display the date, you can use something like this in your model

```
    public function getShortDateTimeFromTimestamp($value)
    {
        if(isset($value))
        {
            $date = date_create();

            date_timestamp_set($date, $value);

            return date_format($date, 'd-m-Y H:i');
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In the view

```
        Published {{ $post->getShortDateTimeFromTimestamp($post->published_at) }}
```

To use current timestamp when storing/updating the resource, you can use

```
published_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
```

Answer (score 0):

this drove me crazy
it's not a Laravel thing
just go to your PHP my admin -> database -> table -> structure
you will find that this column has an Extra attribute of "on update current_time_stamp" Click change then go to attributes change it to the empty option and save
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Alternative solution is to create a migration that run this query to remove the ON UPDATE trigger of the column:

`ALTER TABLE queued_posts CHANGE scheduled_publish_time scheduled_publish_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`